# how to find df cells that are above/below pivot points, but only once

Tags: python, pandas, back-testing

I've got pandas dataframe with candle highs and lows. I've made new column, which shows pivot points (if the value in cell is lowest\highest between two above it an two below it, it has value 1 for lowest or 2 for highest , else 0) example:

| date | high | low | pivot | takes pivot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 207 | 204 | 0 |  |
| 02.01.2020 | 208 | 205 | 0 |  |
| 03.01.2020 | 209 | 205 | 2 |  |
| 04.01.2020 | 207 | 203 | 0 |  |
| 05.01.2020 | 206 | 202 | 0 |  |
| 06.01.2020 | 205 | 200 | 0 |  |
| 07.01.2020 | 204 | 199 | 1 |  |
| 08.01.2020 | 206 | 201 | 0 |  |
| 09.01.2020 | 207 | 202 | 0 |  |
| 10.01.2020 | 208 | 205 | 0 |  |
| 11.01.2020 | 210 | 207 | 0 |  |
| 12.01.2020 | 212 | 209 | 0 |  |
| 13.01.2020 | 214 | 210 | 2 |  |
| 14.01.2020 | 207 | 204 | 0 |  |
| 15.01.2020 | 203 | 202 | 0 |  |
| 16.01.2020 | 201 | 198 | 0 |  |
| 17.01.2020 | 199 | 196 | 0 |  |

i need to find exact candles that made new high or low(according to pivotpoints,not all candles), something like this:  for example in this table takes pivot=1 for 16.01.2020 and takes pivot=2 for 11.01.2020 only(takes pivot = 1 for lows and 2 for highs)

I've tried to make a loop, but cant really understand how exactly it should look

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

`rolling` and use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['high'].rolling(5, center=True).max().eq(df['high'])
cond2 = df['low'].rolling(5, center=True).min().eq(df['low'])
df['pivot'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [2, 1], 0)
```

df

```
    date    high    low pivot
0   01.01.2020  207 204 0
1   02.01.2020  208 205 0
2   03.01.2020  209 205 2
3   04.01.2020  207 203 0
4   05.01.2020  206 202 0
5   06.01.2020  205 200 0
6   07.01.2020  204 199 1
7   08.01.2020  206 201 0
8   09.01.2020  207 202 0
9   10.01.2020  208 205 0
10  11.01.2020  210 207 0
11  12.01.2020  212 209 0
12  13.01.2020  214 210 2
13  14.01.2020  207 204 0
14  15.01.2020  203 202 0
15  16.01.2020  201 198 0
16  17.01.2020  199 196 0
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'date': ['01.01.2020', '02.01.2020', '03.01.2020', '04.01.2020', '05.01.2020', '06.01.2020', '07.01.2020', '08.01.2020', '09.01.2020', '10.01.2020', '11.01.2020', '12.01.2020', '13.01.2020', '14.01.2020', '15.01.2020', '16.01.2020', '17.01.2020'], 'high': [207, 208, 209, 207, 206, 205, 204, 206, 207, 208, 210, 212, 214, 207, 203, 201, 199], 'low': [204, 205, 205, 203, 202, 200, 199, 201, 202, 205, 207, 209, 210, 204, 202, 198, 196]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: I've already done it. the question is how to find values in 'takes pivot' col

Comment: @ГлебДубовенко Then you need to clearly explain the pivot_value. If you manually calculate the pivot_value for each row and explain the logic behind why it is that value, you will be able to get a coded answer.